# Merging chat history from Windows to Linux (.db to .lock)

Tags: skype

I want to merge my Skype chat history from a Windows version, which comes in a file called `main.db` inside my personal folders, with my `main.lock` file, found in my hidden Skype folders on my home computer.  I'm running Linux Mint and Ubuntu both on 32-bit 12.04.

Alternatively, I may need to simply replace the current `.lock` file with a converted version of the older `.db` file. Is there a way I can do this instead?

Answer (score 0):

The .lock file should only be present when Skype is running.

You can likely just replace the .db file with the one from Windows, but I don't know if the data is 100% consistent across platforms in there. You could also just use the `sqlite3` console tool to export from the one database, and then import the resulting data into the existing main.db file on Linux.

However, beware that you may indeed break Skype, and might have to start over.

Comment: Thanks. As there are so many .db and .dbb files, I think this impossible for my level now.